# How to retrieve everything within a object and assign to variable

Tags: javascript

I have a object, computer

```
var computer= {
     Home:{
        values:"sadfasd",
        val:"something else"
     }
    Appllications:{
        one:"dasf",
        two:"twsdf"
    }
}
```

how do I

1. Retrieve everything with computer and log it into a variable, (it will say object Home and object Applications or something like that) and;
2. Log everything in Home or Applications into a variable (it will contain the values of values and val or one and two)

Comment: Um.....`console.log(computer)`

Comment: show exemple of what you expect

Comment: better yet, show an example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to subobjects within an object using the dot notation.

```
var home = computer.Home;
var apps = computer.Applications;
```

or the square bracket notation

```
var home = computer["Home"];
var apps = computer["Applications"];
```

You can log these to the console, for example, using `console.log`

```
console.log(computer.Home);
```

Comment: so access a property dynamically, do i use the square bracket notation or the dot notation?

Comment: @eclipseIzHere it depends what you mean by "dynamically"